# Innacuracy when multiplying integer by float in python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.8

When multiplying 100 by 1.10 the returned value is 110.00000000000001.

Why is that 00000000000001 there? And how do I get around it so it doesn't show up

Code that I ran:

```
def aumentar(valor, porc):
    return valor*((100+porc)/100)


print(aumentar(100, 10))
#When I run this I get 110.00000000000001 shown up on the terminal
```

Comment: [What every programmer should know about floating point arithmetic](https://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: Thank you so much! 
That's exactly what I was looking for